# Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: "passive" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission

Tags: java, android

I've looked at other posts with this error and one solve was they misspelled "permission" and I incorporated a solution found in another from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619783/location-permissions-on-android-5-1) post and while it causes my app to not crash, it causes it to exit because I'm not being granted permission.

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.turtl.decider">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I added both fine location and coarse location permissions to be safe.

Here's the code causing the error:

```
   private void getLocation() throws SecurityException {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (isPermissionGranted("ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",context)) {
            loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
        } else {
            showAlert("Insufficent Permissions", "Please grant this app GPS permissions to continue.");
        }
    }
```

And the code I copied from the solution I linked to:

```
public static boolean isPermissionGranted(String permission, Context c) {
    //int res = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission);
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(c, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

I'm using Android API level 24 on a Nexus 6p emulator. Like I said, the check if the permission is being granted is causing the app not to crash because it's skipping that line, however it's just exiting.

I ran it on my personal device (API 23) with the same result. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug #1: `isPermissionGranted("ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",context)` is incorrect, as that is not the right string. Use `isPermissionGranted(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, context)` to pull in the proper string.

Bug #2: `<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>` should be `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>`, as there is no permission by that name, though there is a hardware feature by that name.

Also, you will eventually need to call `requestPermissions()` to request `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, as your app does not hold it.

Comment: This certainly helped, however now it's giving me an error: `double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference` when I try to display the lat and long of the location, in a line `showAlert(String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));` which I wrote right under the 4th line down in the `getLocation` function. Do you have any suggestion on why it's seeing this as a null pointer?

Comment: @CS2016: "Do you have any suggestion on why it's seeing this as a null pointer?" -- sure. `getLastKnownLocation()` returned `null`. This happens much of the time. It is [documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)) to return `null`. You use that method as an optimization, not as a primary way of getting the location. See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html